# Does the CL Visit API still work on iOS 14 when only approximate always allow location is granted? (not precise location)

Tags: ios, core-location, ios14

From initial testing it appears that the CLVisit API does nothing when a iOS 14 device is granted 'Always' location permission but the "Precise Location" is disabled.

Does the CLVisit API still work with "precise location" disabled? And if yes, how so? So far it has been said that approximate location is 1-20km polled up to 4 times per hour.

Shouldn't this mean that a long visit to a place far away will be reported? I have driven over 20km and stayed for several hours and there were no visits reported by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work?  Yes.  Visits are still reported and comparing the visits reported on one phone with iOS 13 and a second with iOS 14 and precise location disabled, I see the same number of visits reported with approximately the same arrival/departure times.

Does it work well or as you probably want?  No.

I just tested using an app of mine that uses `CLVisit` - On iOS 14 without precise location it reported a visit with a horizontal accuracy of 6.8km and the center of the visit was about 3 or 4km from my actual location.

In the image below, the selected annotation is the location reported by `CLVisit` without precise location. The green shaded circle is the accuracy reported with that visit.  The blue marker is my actual location when the visit was recorded.

I would suggest that you need to encourage users to enable precise location for any apps that make use of `CLVisit`.

[image]